# Where do you report bugs with TextTransform.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I recently installed Visual Studio 2017 on my Windows 10 machine. I am currently in need of repairing the TextTransform.exe (v15.0.26208.0) file as this version is refusing to compile any T4 template files.

I have the TextTransform.exe (v14.0.25420.1) which came with the Visual Studio 2015 installation, it works compiles the same T4 template file which v15 refuses to compile. I could simply use the older version, however, we're trying to not have to rely on older software in an attempt to stay with the latest up-to-date versions to prevent "downtime" risks.

Where do you report bugs for this particular software? I tried using *The* Google, but the results were not helpful.

Alternative Question:
Is there a standalone installation in which I can install/use to repair the version I have installed on my PC?

Any help is greatly appreciated! -Thanks

EDIT:
To give a little more information, I've already repaired via the Visual Studio 2017 installation, but that did not fix it. So I think the question should be more about where to report the bug rather than if there is a stand alone installation to repair the issue.

Comment: Note: I ended up reporting this through the Visual Studio Feedback center. While I am not sure if that is the proper location, I am hoping that Microsoft will be able to at least get it to the proper people to look into the issue. This issue seems to be directly tied to the version which comes with Visual Studio 2017 installation. I tested it on 3 different computers and each one of them had the same issue.